# Setting variable content equal to strings and set varaibles

Tags: php, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm basically trying to output the text and the variables into a custom HTML field. I'm able to pull the info and output the html without any issue, but I can't get it to work with the variables.

```
$field["content"] = "Lots of companies in the ", $input_industry, "industry are using SMS for their ", $input_department, "teams.";
```

Ideally, the output would be "Lots of companies in the [inputted industry] are using SMS for their [department] teams.

Comment: simply replaces the commas with periods, when concatenating stings in php

Comment: Hi Andrew, you'd better put the title more clearly and focus.
It takes me some time getting the background, it's about PHP variable substitution. It would improve the chance of being answered after you refine the title.